# modal popup and also open a link in new tab

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modal popup. I want to have the option that instead of "popup", a certain link will open in a new window instead of an `iframe`.

This is what I am using right now:

```html
<div class="modal-content" style="max-width:767px;">
  <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span> 
  <iframe src="URL"></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open link in new tab, why you are using modal, use anchor tag with target="_blank" as below

```
<a href="example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Comment: It's on a sidebar in WordPress. There is a button that opens a popup with a different URL on each page.

On some pages, I want a new tab to open.

The button ID set on this SIDEBAR is "MYBTN"

And in the page code and site there is an area where I insert a dedicated link on each page.

In some, I want it to open in a separate window, without damaging the pages where I want POPUP still to be.

I tried the option you registered, it didn't work.

So how to do it?